# Different behaviour for same code in different languages

Tags: javascript, c++, xxtea

I am trying to decrypt [Block TEA](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA) in Javascript (Node.js). I have tried to do the same thing in C++ and it works as expected:

```
#define DELTA 0x9e3779b9
#define MX (((z>>5^y<<2) + (y>>3^z<<4)) ^ ((sum^y) + (key[(p&3)^e] ^ z)))

#define CRYPT_WORDS (64-4)/4
#define CRYPT_OFFSET 1

void btea_decrypt(uint32_t *v, int n, int base_rounds, uint32_t const key[4])
{
    uint32_t y, z, sum;
    unsigned p, rounds, e;

    /* Decoding Part */
    rounds = base_rounds + 52/n;
    sum = rounds*DELTA;
    y = v[0];

    do {
        e = (sum >> 2) & 3;
        for (p=n-1; p>0; p--) {
            z = v[p-1];
            y = v[p] -= MX;
        }

        z = v[n-1];
        y = v[0] -= MX;
        sum -= DELTA;
    } while (--rounds);
}

int main()
{
    static const uint32_t key[4] = {0x875bcc51, 0xa7637a66, 0x50960967, 0xf8536c51};
    uint32_t buf[64] = {16,  23, 163, 242, 214, 213, 125,  48, 167,  44, 232,
        23, 160, 192, 244, 116,  38, 255, 200,  38,  43,  57,
        18, 235, 206, 103, 161, 210, 187, 164,  42, 227, 139,
        248, 141, 205,  51, 132, 115, 233,  39,  53, 136, 207,
        238, 190, 111,  57, 117, 233,  67, 133, 165,  84, 154,
        161, 165, 173,  76, 115, 108,   0,   0,  71};
    uint32_t cryptpart[CRYPT_WORDS];

    // Decrypt encrypted portion
    for (int i = 0; i < CRYPT_WORDS; i++) {
        cryptpart[i] =
            ((uint32_t)buf[CRYPT_OFFSET+4*i  ]) << 0  |
            ((uint32_t)buf[CRYPT_OFFSET+4*i+1]) << 8  |
            ((uint32_t)buf[CRYPT_OFFSET+4*i+2]) << 16 |
            ((uint32_t)buf[CRYPT_OFFSET+4*i+3]) << 24;
    }

    btea_decrypt(cryptpart, CRYPT_WORDS, 1, key);

    for (int i = 0; i < CRYPT_WORDS; i++) {
        buf[CRYPT_OFFSET+4*i  ] = cryptpart[i] >> 0;
        buf[CRYPT_OFFSET+4*i+1] = cryptpart[i] >> 8;
        buf[CRYPT_OFFSET+4*i+2] = cryptpart[i] >> 16;
        buf[CRYPT_OFFSET+4*i+3] = cryptpart[i] >> 24;
    }

    for (const auto& e : buf) {
        std::cout << e << ", ";
    }
}
```

And it outputs:

```
16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 65280, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3561881601, 13913600, 54350, 212, 393407394, 1536747, 6002, 23, 3612094810, 14109745, 55116, 215, 589329, 2302, 8, 0, 5439472, 21247, 82, 0, 0, 0, 71,
```

But using the same code (ported) in Node.js:

```
function btea_decrypt(v, n, base_rounds, key)
{
    let y, z, sum;
    let p, rounds, e;

    /* Decoding Part */
    rounds = base_rounds + 52/n;
    sum = rounds*0x9e3779b9;
    y = v[0];

    do {
        e = (sum >> 2) & 3;
        for (p=n-1; p>0; p--) {
            z = v[p-1];
            y = v[p] -= (((z>>5^y<<2) + (y>>3^z<<4)) ^ ((sum^y) + (key[(p&3)^e] ^ z)));
        }

        z = v[n-1];
        y = v[0] -= (((z>>5^y<<2) + (y>>3^z<<4)) ^ ((sum^y) + (key[(p&3)^e] ^ z)));
        sum -= 0x9e3779b9;
    } while (--rounds);
    return v;
}

function main() {
    let key = [0x875bcc51, 0xa7637a66, 0x50960967, 0xf8536c51];
    let buf = [16,  23, 163, 242, 214, 213, 125,  48, 167,  44, 232,
   23, 160, 192, 244, 116,  38, 255, 200,  38,  43,  57,
   18, 235, 206, 103, 161, 210, 187, 164,  42, 227, 139,
  248, 141, 205,  51, 132, 115, 233,  39,  53, 136, 207,
  238, 190, 111,  57, 117, 233,  67, 133, 165,  84, 154,
  161, 165, 173,  76, 115, 108,   0,   0,  71];
    let cryptpart = [];

    // Decrypt encrypted portion
    for (let i = 0; i < (64-4)/4; i++) {
    cryptpart[i] =
        (buf[1+4*i  ]) << 0  |
        (buf[1+4*i+1]) << 8  |
        (buf[1+4*i+2]) << 16 |
        (buf[1+4*i+3]) << 24;
    }

    cryptpart = btea_decrypt(cryptpart, (64-4)/4, 1, key);

    for (let i = 0; i < (64-4)/4; i++) {
        buf[1+4*i  ] = cryptpart[i] >> 0;
        buf[1+4*i+1] = cryptpart[i] >> 8;
        buf[1+4*i+2] = cryptpart[i] >> 16;
        buf[1+4*i+3] = cryptpart[i] >> 24;
    }

    console.log(buf)
}
```

It remains stuck in `do ... while` loop forever.

I figured out, that Javascript and C++ handle `0x9e3779b9` differently, because `0x9e3779b9 * 15` in JS equals 39816536535 and 1161830871 in C++. What is wrong with math in C++ and how to realize this in JS?

Sorry if my English isn't the best.

Comment: C++ has a 64-bit integer type; JavaScript does not. Modern JavaScript supports a "big integer" type.

Comment: What you are experiencing is called integer overflow.  Not sure if JS even does that.

Comment: In JS, `rounds` is being interpreted as a float because of the division in the assignment, and therefore is probably never 0 - thus the loop never ends. Use `Math.floor()`, `Math.ceil()`, `Math.round()`, or `Math.trunc()` to get an integer from `rounds`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is caused by an integer overflow. A unint32_t is an integer of fixed size 2^32 bits. 0x9e3779b9 * 15 is 39816536535 which is approx 2^35.

This means you get an overflow as the memory location is simply not big enough to hold your number. Javascript does not have this problem as its not statically typed and the size allocated in memory will increase dynamically to hold it.

Use a larger datatype for C++, like an `unsigned long` or `size_t` (alias for `unsigned long` on most systems). Preferably use `auto` to let the compiler decide for you:

```cpp
auto sum = rounds*0x9e3779b9;
```

This will fix your issue and ensure sum is large enough to hold the number

Side notes: There is quite a lot of C in your C++, in C++ we try and avoid `#define`s and declare variables when we first use them, not at the top of the scope. When writing C++ code prefer `const auto x` instead of `#define x` (possibly `constexpr` if its a basic type)